# mysql working out percentages using a subquery

Tags: mysql

Can someone please help in working out percentages of my resultset I am unable to do this on the subquery:

```
SELECT
CntryCD, 
Country,
SectyCD,
SecurityType,
COUNT(SecID) as SecurityCount,

concat(count(SecID)/(select count(SecID) from wca.scmst)*100, '%') as Percentage

FROM
(
            select distinct
            wca.region.CntryCD,
            wca.region.Country,
            wca.scmst.SectyCD,
            secty.SecurityDescriptor as 'SecurityType',
            wca.bond.SecID 
            from wca.bond
            inner join wca.scmst on wca.bond.secid = wca.scmst.secid
            inner join wca.secty on wca.scmst.sectycd = wca.secty.SectyCD
            left outer join wca.scexh on wca.scmst.secid = wca.scexh.secid
            left outer join wca.exchg on wca.scexh.exchgcd = wca.exchg.exchgcd
            left outer join wca.region on ifnull(wca.exchg.cntrycd,'UB') = wca.region.cntrycd
            where
            wca.bond.actflag <> 'D'
            and wca.scmst.actflag <> 'D'
            and wca.scmst.statusflag <> 'I'

            union

            select distinct
            wca.region.CntryCD,
            wca.region.Country,
            wca.scmst.SectyCD,
            secty.SecurityDescriptor as 'SecurityType',
            wca.scmst.SecID
            from wca.scmst
            inner join wca.sectygrp on wca.scmst.sectycd = wca.sectygrp.sectycd and 3> sectygrp.secgrpid
            inner join wca.secty on wca.scmst.sectycd = wca.secty.SectyCD
            left outer join wca.scexh on wca.scmst.secid = wca.scexh.secid
            left outer join wca.exchg on wca.scexh.exchgcd = wca.exchg.exchgcd
            left outer join wca.region on ifnull(wca.exchg.cntrycd,'UB') = wca.region.cntrycd
            where
            wca.scmst.actflag <> 'D'
            and wca.scexh.liststatus <> 'D'
            and (wca.scexh.actflag <> 'D' or wca.scexh.actflag is null)
            and wca.scmst.statusflag <> 'I'
) AS T1
where
country = 'United Kingdom'
group by Country, SectyCD;
```

I am getting the following resultset:

[image]

The percentages are wrong - I am trying to work out the percentage of each row from the total of all rows which should be 24218. For example first record count 13663/24218*100=56.4167%. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to override the order of operators. 13663/(24218*100) = 0.00564. (13663*100)/24218 = 56.4167 so ```concat((count(SecID)*100)/(select count(SecID) from wca.scmst), '%')``` may work better.

Comment: I got the exact same resultset using your bit of code unfortunately

Comment: The rammifications of your joins is unclear to me, but the fact that you are putting SecID inside COUNT makes me wonder if you might mean COUNT(DISTINCT SecID).

Comment: @Dougie `*` and `/` both associate left to right, so `x / y * z` is equivalent to `(x / y) * z`

Comment: The subquery doesn't return all rows from `wca.scmst`, it only returns the rows that match the `WHERE` conditions. So the total count from the subquery will not add up to the count from the whole table.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.0, you could put the subquery in a CTE. Then you can get the total rows in the subquery and divide the per-row count by that to get the percentage.

Comment: Without a CTE, you can define the subquery as a view and use that.

Comment: the version i an using is 5.6.29, I'm not sure how to go about defining sub query as a view any example code would be appreciated.I was about to load my output into a new table and do the counts and percentage calculation on that